# How to execute a command to compile a .tex file to a pdf?

Tags: java, pdflatex

I am writing a web application, that can put together several math problems and make a downloadable pdf document out of them.

So I am trying to convert .tex file with the tasks into a pdf one.
So I am trying to execute this command through command line with

```
./src/main/java/pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode ./src/main/java/example.tex
```

but it displays the following message

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `article.cls'.
<*> article.cls 
                ./src/main/java/example.tex
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> article.cls 
                ./src/main/java/example.tex
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on texput.log.

Exited with 1
```

However the file article.cls is in the same directory as the .tex file and the pdflatex.exe.

How do I tell the pdflatex to take notice of the required file or maybe I should take a different approach.

Comment: Does it work if you put the article.cls file in your Tex home folder, as suggested here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te

Comment: Try with a minimal tex distribution instead of apparently randomly assembling files...